# What are the factors that determine how much money is earned after a round?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

After every round I play during matchmaking, the money awarded is varied from 1400+. Are there any factors I should keep in mind whilst finishing a round? Specifically in bomb defuse maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are losing:

- $1400 after losing the first round
- $1900 after losing 2 rounds in a row
- $2400 after losing 3 rounds in a row
- $2900 after losing 4 rounds in a row
- $3400 after losing 5 or more rounds in a row

So it is actually a $500 increase after each loss until you win a round. Then you would get $1400 again.

If your Team is playing Terrorists and your Team has planted the bomb, but lose the round, all Terrorists receive additional $800 on top of the above.

If your Team eliminates all players, you get $3250, if you are playing Terrorist and your bomb explodes, you get $3500. In hostage maps you actually get $3600.

Single team members can be affected by the "No Income" penalty. For example, if you have the bomb and the time runs out, you would get no reward since you did not follow the objective. If you are a CT and on a hostage map and your team loses with you still alive, your reward is canceled too. This however, can only affect a player, not the whole team, unless the whole is just not playing.

Additionally you can have a penalty of $300 per hit on a hostage.

Weapons are also a factor in what monetary reward a single team member can get:

- Pistols award $300 per kill
- Rifles award $300 per kill, except the AWP awards 100$ per kill
- SMG's award $600 per kill
- Shotguns award $900 per kill
- Heavy Weapons award $300 per kill
- Grenades award $900 per kill
- A knife kill awards 1500$ per kill

Comment: If I drop the bomb before the end of the round, do I still get the penalty ?

Comment: @Michel If you drop it to the ground, yes.